# Convergence in metric and in measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(X, A)$, with the semimetric 
$$ d(f,g) = \int \frac{|f-g|}{1+ |f-g|}d\mu$$
on all real-valued, A-measurable functions.
 Show that $$\lim_n d(f_n, f) = 0$$ holds iff 
$(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in measure.

I know that convergence in mean implies convergence in measure but 
$ \int \frac{|f-g|}{1+ |f-g|}d\mu \leq   \int {|f-g|}d\mu $
and also 
$ \mu(\{x\in X\ : |f_n(x) - f(x) > \epsilon\}) \leq   \int {|f-g|}d\mu $. 
So I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a remark: the map $x\mapsto \frac x{1+x}$ is increasing over the set of non-negative real numbers, and is bounded by $1$.

If $f_n\to f$ in measure, fix $\varepsilon$ and integrate over $\{|f_n-f|>\varepsilon\}$ and $\{|f_n-f|\leqslant \varepsilon\}$.

Conversely, if $d(f_n,f)\to 0$, then $\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\mu\{|f_n-f|>\varepsilon\}\to 0$ (integrating over the set $\{|f_n-f|>\varepsilon\}$).

Comment: thanks! I have not seen any of those "tricks" like integrating over both parts. Can you please expand. And how do you get the implication in the conversely part and how does it matter?

Comment: Does the edit help?