# Convergence in metric and in Borel measure

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have the space ($\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R},\lambda$) and define 
e $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $h(t) = 1/(1+t^2)$.

a) Prove that the formula $$d(f,g) = \int \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|}hd\lambda$$
defines a semimetric on the collection of all real-valued Borel measurable function on $\mathbb{R}.$

b) $\lim_n d(f_n,f) = 0$ holds iff $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in measure on each bounded subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$.

The first part seems not so hard. Should follow from the definitions, 
but how do one to the b)? Why does it matter that the subintervals are bounded ?

This is somewhat analogous to my last question [Convergence in metric and in measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456355/convergence-in-metric-and-in-measure)
(from the book Measure theory of Donald Cohn, page 96)

Comment: What is the role of the auxilliary function $h$ you have defined here?

Comment: To make the function smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove (a), use the fact that the function 
$$x\mapsto {x\over 1 + x}$$
is increasing on $[0,\infty)$. This is how you get the triangle inequality.