# Convergence in measure on each bounded subinterval

Tags: measure-theory

On ($\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}),\lambda$) and define $h(t) = 1/(1+t^2)$ and
$$d(f,g) = \int \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|}hd\lambda$$

If $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in measure on each bounded subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$, then $\lim_n d(f_n,f) = 0$.

This problem has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456382/convergence-in-metric-and-in-borel-measure). I can show that $$\int_I \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}h d\lambda \to 0$$ for every bounded subinterval $I$. How to proceed?

Comment: If your interval $I$ is large enough, the integral over the complement of $I$ is small (uniformly in $n$).

Comment: The integrand is bounded above by $h$, and the integral of $\int_r^\infty h\,d\lambda$ goes to $0$ as $r \to \infty$