# Convergence in Measure in a Finite Measure Space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

> Assume $m(E) < \infty$. For two measurable functions $g$ and $h$, define $$\rho(g,h) = \int_E \frac{|g-h|}{1+|g-h|}.$$ Show that $f_n \to f$ in measure on $E$ if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \rho(f_n,f)=0$.

This problem has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456355/convergence-in-metric-and-in-measure)); however, I am having trouble understanding Davide's nebulous and somewhat misleading suggestions (at least to my mind), which I now reproduce:

> First, a remark: the map $x\mapsto \frac x{1+x}$ is increasing over the set of non-negative real numbers, and is bounded by $1$.
>
> If $f_n\to f$ in measure, fix $\varepsilon$ and integrate over $\{|f_n-f|>\varepsilon\}$ and $\{|f_n-f|\leqslant \varepsilon\}$.
>
> Conversely, if $d(f_n,f)\to 0$, then $\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\mu\{|f_n-f|>\varepsilon\}\to 0$ (integrating over the set $\{|f_n-f|>\varepsilon\}$).

His first remark is somewhat confusing, for it seems to hint as using the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem for convergence in measure, where $1$ serves as the integrable function that dominates the sequence $\frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}$ of measurable functions converging to $0$ in measure. Hence,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|} = \int_E 0 = 0$$

Yet he goes on to suggest integrating over $\{|f_n-f| > \epsilon\}$ and $\{|f_n-f| \le \epsilon\}$. Well, I tried this but I couldn't figure out it. For the first integral, we get

$$\int_{\{|f_n-f| > \epsilon\}} \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|} \le \int_{\{|f_n-f| > \epsilon\}}  \le m(\{x : |f_n(x)-f(x)| > \epsilon \} \to 0 \mbox{ as } n \to \infty $$

However, I couldn't figure out how to show that the second integral is zero or at least converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. I tried showing that $\int_{\{|f_n-f| \le \epsilon \}} \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}$ is bounded above by $\epsilon$ and then letting $\epsilon \to 0^+$, which would actually show that $\int_{\{|f_n-f| \le \epsilon \}} \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|} = 0$ for every $n$, but I couldn't get just $\epsilon$ alone. The best I could do is get $\epsilon \cdot m(\{x : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \le \epsilon\})$, which doesn't obviously go $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

---

As for the converse, I believe I was able to follow his suggestion. If $|f_n-f| > \epsilon$, then $\frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|} > \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$ and therefore $\int_E \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|} > \int_E \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon} > \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} \int_{\{f_n-f| > \epsilon\}} = \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} m(\{x : |f_n(x)-f(x)| > \epsilon\})$ from which we get

$$0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|} \ge \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} \lim_{n \to \infty} m(\{x : |f_n(x)-f(x)| > \epsilon\})$$

and hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} m(\{x : |f_n(x)-f(x)| > \epsilon\})=0$.

Comment: $\epsilon\cdot m(\{x:|f_n(x)−f(x)|≤\epsilon\})$ does go to zero as $\epsilon\to 0^+$. This follows since $m(\{x:|f_n(x)−f(x)|≤\epsilon\})\le m(E)$, and the problem assumed $m(E)<\infty$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Oh! Drats! It's so simple! So this means that $\int_{\{|f_n-f| \le \epsilon\} = 0$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, right? That's somewhat unexpected.

Comment: Your last comment is not correct. Why would it be the case that $\int_{\{|f_n-f| \le \epsilon\}} |f_n-f|/(1+|f_n-f|)= 0$? You are integrating a positive function over a set of positive measure.

Answer (score 3):

Let me give more details. Let $$I(\varepsilon):=\int_{\{|f_n-f| \leqslant\epsilon \}} \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}=\int\mathbf 1{\{|f_n-f| \leqslant\epsilon \}} \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}.$$
Since the map $x\mapsto x/(1+x)$ is increasing, we certainly have (point wise)
$$
\mathbf 1{\{|f_n-f| \leqslant\epsilon \}} \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}\leqslant \mathbf 1{\{|f_n-f| \leqslant\epsilon \}} \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}\leqslant\epsilon \mathbf 1{\{|f_n-f| \leqslant\epsilon \}}
$$
hence integrating, 
we get 
$$
\int\mathbf 1{\{|f_n-f| \leqslant\epsilon \}} \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}\leqslant \varepsilon\cdot  m\left(\{|f_n-f| \leqslant\epsilon \}\right)\leqslant \varepsilon \cdot m(E).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Two straightforward inequalities settle the matter. For a measurable function $f$ and $0<\epsilon<1$,
$$
m\{x\in E: |f(x)|>\epsilon\}\le{1+\epsilon\over\epsilon}\int_E{|f|\over1+|f|}\,dm
$$
and
$$
\int_E{|f|\over1+|f|}\,dm\le\epsilon m(E)+m\{x\in E: |f(x)|>\epsilon\}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have by Holder's inequality that 
\begin{align*}
m(\{x\in E: |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\leq\epsilon\})&=\int_{E}\chi_{|f_{n}-f|\leq\epsilon}\chi_{E}dm\\
&\leq\|\chi_{|f_{n}-f|\leq\epsilon}\|_{L^{\infty}(E)}\|\chi_{E}\|_{L^{1}(E)}\\
&\leq\epsilon\|\chi_{E}\|_{L^{1}(E)}\\
&=m(E)\epsilon,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\int_{|f_{n}-f|\leq\epsilon}\dfrac{|f_{n}-f|}{1+|f_{n}-f|}dm\leq\int_{|f_{n}-f|\leq\epsilon}dm=m(\{x\in E:|f_{n}-f|\leq\epsilon\})\leq m(E)\epsilon.
\end{align*}