# Two kinds of Metrics of Convergence in Measure

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

There are many kinds of metrics that can induce the topology of convergences in measure. Two most common metrics are

1. [Here is the first one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596948/convergence-in-measure-topology/1602609#1602609).

$ 
d(f,g) := \inf_{\delta > 0} \big(\mu(|f-g|>\delta) + \delta\big)
$

2. [Here is the second one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456355/convergence-in-metric-and-in-measure), which is the most common.

$
d(f,g) = \int \frac{|f-g|}{1+ |f-g|}d\mu
$

I have three questions:

Q1 I am trying to prove the Triangle inequality of the first metric. I have done so far:

$
  \mu\left\{ x\in X:\left|f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right|>\delta\right\} +\delta
\le \mu\left\{ x\in X:\left|f\left(x\right)-h\left(x\right)\right|>\frac{\delta}{2}\right\} +\frac{\delta}{2}+\mu\left\{ x\in X:\left|h\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right|>\frac{\delta}{2}\right\} +\frac{\delta}{2}
$

But I have no idea what to do next.

Q2 What is the difference between the two metrics? Both metrics can induce the topology of convergence in measure. As far as I am concerned,  the second metric is used only in probability contexts or in the case the measure is finite. I wonder whether this statement is right. If it is true, what's wrong with the second metric when the measure is not finite?

Q3 Given a measure space $\left(X,\mathscr{F},\mu\right)$ and let $L^{0}\left(X,\mathscr{F},\mu\right)$ be the vector space of all real-valued measurable functions on $\left(X,\mathscr{F},\mu\right)$.
If both metrics can be defined on $L^{0}\left(X,\mathscr{F},\mu\right)$, are the topologies of these two spaces the same?

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1: let $A=d(f,h)$ and $B=d(h,g)$. Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there exist $\delta_1 >0$ and $\delta_2 >0$ such that $\mu(|f-h| >\delta_1)+\delta_1 <A+\epsilon$ and
$\mu(|h-g| >\delta_2)+\delta_2 <B+\epsilon$. Note that $|f-g| >\delta_1+\delta_2$ implies that either $|f-h| >\delta_1$ or $|h-g| >\delta_2$. Hence $d(f,g) \leq \mu(|f-g| >\delta_1+\delta_2\leq A+B+2\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we get $d(f,g) \leq d(f,h)+d(h,g)$.

If $\mu$ is not finite it is not true that all bounded measurable functions  are integrable. The second definition cannot be used for infinite measures since metrics cannot take the value $\infty$.

For a finite measure both metrics yield the same topology since $f_n \to f$ in one metric iff $f_n \to f$ in the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will fill out the proof. Do you have any idea on the Q1?

Comment: @Leoalan.Huang I have edited my answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: For the second definition, couldn't one just use the metric $\min\{d, 1\}$, even for an infinite measure? The induced topology should be the same.

Comment: @DannyHansen $\min \{d,1\}$ gives a bad metric. The distance between  any two different constant  functions  $f$ $g$  would be $1$, so $\frac 1  n$ would not converge to $0$!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Right, but it's only bad because $d$ is bad (since they are topologically equivalent, indeed they have the same Cauchy sequences). What I'm saying is that the issue isn't that $d$ isn't a finite metric, the issue is that it gives the wrong topology when $\mu$ isn't finite.