# Convergence in a complete measure is metrizable

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, metric-spaces, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a *complete* measure space,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$, and
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$.
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$.

For simplicity, we write
$$
\mu (|f - g| > \delta) := \mu (\{x \in X : |f (x) - g(x)| > \delta\})
\quad \forall \delta >0.
$$

Notice that the completeness of $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ implies $\{x \in X : |f (x) - g(x)| > \delta\} \in \mathcal A$. We define
$$
\hat \rho (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \mu (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}
\quad \forall f, g \in L^0 (X).
$$

Then

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3298609/368425) $\hat \rho$ is a [pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pseudometric_space#Definition) on $L^0 (X)$.
>
> *Proof* Clearly, $\hat \rho (f, f)=0$ and $\hat \rho (f, g) = \hat \rho (g, f)$. It remains to verify the triangle inequality. Let $f,g,h \in L^0 (X)$. Fix $\varepsilon >0$. There are $\delta_1, \delta_2 >0$ such that
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \varepsilon + \hat \rho (f, g) &> \mu (|f - g| > \delta_1)  +\delta_1, \\
> \varepsilon + \hat \rho (g, h) &> \mu (|g - h| > \delta_2)  +\delta_2.
> \end{align*}
> $$
> Notice that $|f-h| > \delta_1 + \delta_2$ implies $|f-g| > \delta_1$ or $|g-h| > \delta_2$. Then
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> 2\varepsilon + \hat \rho (f, g) + \hat \rho (g, h) &> \mu (|f - g| > \delta_1) + \mu (|g-h| > \delta_2)  +\delta_1 +\delta_2 \\
> &\ge \mu (|f - h|> \delta_1 +\delta_2)  +\delta_1 +\delta_2 \\
> &\ge \hat \rho (f, h).
> \end{align*}
> $$
> The claim follows by taking the limit $\varepsilon \to 0^+$.

I would like to verify a claim in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596948/the-topology-associated-to-convergence-in-measure) thread, i.e.,

> **Theorem** $\hat \rho (f_n, f) \to 0$ IFF $f_n \to f$ [in measure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions), i.e.,
> $$
> \mu ( |f_n - f| > \varepsilon) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
> \quad \forall \varepsilon >0.
> $$

Could you have a check on my below attempt? Thank you so much for your help!

---

1. $\implies$

Assume $\hat \rho (f_n, f) \to 0$. Fix an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. We will prove
$$
\mu ( |f_n - f| > \varepsilon) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0.
$$

Fix $0 < \varepsilon' < \varepsilon$. There is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that
$$
\inf_{\delta >0} \{ \mu (|f_n - f| > \delta)  +\delta \} < \varepsilon'
\quad \forall n >N.
$$

Then there is $\delta_n >0$ such that
$$
\mu (|f_n - f| > \delta_n)  +\delta_n < \varepsilon'
\quad \forall n >N.
$$

Then for all $n > N$, we have $\delta_n < \varepsilon' <\varepsilon$ and $\mu (|f_n - f| > \delta_n)  < \varepsilon'$. Then for all $n > N$, we have $\mu (|f_n - f| > \varepsilon)   < \varepsilon'$. Because $\varepsilon'$ can be arbitrarily small, the claim then follows.

2. $\impliedby$

Assume $f_n \to f$ in measure. Fix an arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$. It suffices to prove that
$$
\limsup_n \hat \rho (f_n, f) = \limsup_n \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \mu (|f_n - f| > \delta)  +\delta \} \le \varepsilon.
$$

Fix some $\varepsilon' < \varepsilon/2$. Then $\mu ( |f_n - f| > \varepsilon') \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$. Then there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that
$$
\mu ( |f_n - f| > \varepsilon') < \varepsilon'
\quad \forall n > N.
$$

Then
$$
\mu ( |f_n - f| > \varepsilon') + \varepsilon' < \varepsilon
\quad \forall n > N.
$$

Then
$$
\inf_{\delta >0} \{ \mu (|f_n - f| > \delta)  +\delta \} \le \varepsilon
\quad \forall n > N.
$$

Then
$$
\limsup_n \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \mu (|f_n - f| > \delta)  +\delta \} \le \varepsilon.
$$

The claim then follows.